# Access other item contents within a QGraphicsScene

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsitem, qgraphicsscene

I have a *dialog.cpp* file, it is within here I created my `QGraphicsScene` which uses the `QGraphicsView`.

I created two classes that inherit `QGraphicsPixmapItem`, `"Vehicle"` and `"Junction"`. Both of these objects are added to the same `QGraphicsScene` in my *dialog.cpp* file.

I want to call a method which is a member of `"Junction"` from my `"Vehicle"` object. The method returns a boolean value which I need.

This is more of a c++ orientated question, as I'm sure there's an easy solution which makes use of accessing a parent.

Background info on project: Each `"Vehicle"` moves along a road and approaches a `"Junction"`. The vehicle must then ask the junction "does my lane have a green light to go?", the junction will then reply `"true/false"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reviewing possible solutions via the QT documentation I have partly resolved the issue.

Calling `this->scene()` allows access to member functions of the scene, on which your object was added. Since I know the co-ordinates of my object I call, `this->scene()->itemAt(240,0);` to retrieve a pointer to the item.

The pointer returned is the uppermost item on the scene at the co-ordinates supplied. If this provides a problem alternately use `scene()->items()` to retrieve a list of all the items on the scene.

However, this only gives access to the *item* and not the vector in which the item is stored. I have been looking into using the `->parent()` function and think this may be the solution, combined with dynamically casting it to the required pointer. Will update the answer if I find a full solution.